# Generate Age as on a particular date

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to generate age as on a particular date (loan disbursement date).

```
def age(dob, disdate): 
    dob =df['dob']
    disdate =df['disb_date']
    return disdate.dt.year - dob.dt.year - ((disdate.dt.month, disdate.dt.day) < (dob.dt.month, dob.dt.day)) 

df['age_at_loan'] = df.apply(lambda x: age(x['dob'], x['disb_date']), axis=1)
```

I get the below error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can you please help me identify the mistake?

Comment: It would be helpful to get which formats are dates passed in `disdate`. Comparing dates like that in a tuple looks odd.

Comment: You override `dob` and `disdate` inside the function which are already passed as arguments. Simply remove the first two lines of the function...